# how to move indesign pages similar to moving artboards in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, page-layout

i'm making a 16 page layout, but the first and last page are not next to each other like the other pages but are separate.

thank you very much! :D

Comment: That is because you have 'facing pages' checked in your document settings. with that setting, InDesign presents things as if you were creating a book or booklet with single front and back pages and two-page spreads for all others.

Comment: Besides: welcome, indesign newb, to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

The first and last are not supposed to be next to each other. The first page of a book is always a **right page** and the last a left one. But that has nothing to do with artboards.